# How do I plot 3 dimensionally in a domain specified by a function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to plot 3 dimensionally with `matplotlib.pyplot`, but only in a specific domain whose boundary is set by a function. Here is the code

```py
import numpy
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.ticker
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def get_x1min(pT, eta, rS):
    return (pT * numpy.exp(eta)) / (rS - pT * numpy.exp(- eta))

def get_x2(x1, pT, eta, rS):
    return (x1 * pT * numpy.exp(- eta)) / (x1 * rS - pT * numpy.exp(eta))

rS = 1960.0
eta = 0.0
pT = [66.0, 77.5, 89.5, 92.0, 94.0, 96.0, 98.0, 100.0, 103.0, 105.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 118.5, 136.5, 157.5, 182.0, 200.0, 209.5, 241.5, 278.5, 321.0, 370.0, 426.5, 492.0]

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x1_test = numpy.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 20)
x1_test, pT = numpy.meshgrid(x1_test, pT)
x2_test = get_x2(x1_test, pT, eta, rS)
ax.plot_surface(x1_test, pT, x2_test, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap('rainbow'))
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

This works fine BUT the domain is a rectangle,  and the only change needed is to have `x1_test` just start from a minimum that can be obtained from function `get_x1min`. Is there any method of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the unwanted values to `np.nan`, then they will not be plotted. Note though that there seems to be some problems with the colormapping. You can get around this using the `vmin` and `vmax` keywords:

```
mask = x1_test< get_x1min(pT, eta, rS)
x2_test[mask] = numpy.nan

ax.plot_surface(
    x1_test, pT, x2_test, rstride=1, cstride=1,
    cmap=matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap('rainbow'),
    vmin = numpy.nanmin(x2_test),
    vmax = numpy.nanmax(x2_test),    
    )

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

The rest of the code would stay the same. The result looks something like this:

[image: result of the OP's code patched with the code posted above]